# Spark on Windows, Yarn on Linux

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, pyspark

I have yarn service running top on hadoop 2.0 on Linux environment and I have Spark on my windows machine. I can run Spark locally on my windows.But I am trying point my Windows-Spark to Yarn on Hadoop(Linux) side to utilize Yarn containers.
How can set HADOOP_CONF_DIR on windows side so it can point and see /etc/hadoop/conf on linux side. Thank you